# How to display hundreds of lines of output in a Ruby CLI tool

Tags: ruby, output, command-line-interface

I'm building a Ruby CLI tool that requires outputting large amounts of data. The script shows a list of changes and asks the user to confirm they want to continue to the next change set. This diff contains structured output that is necessarily very verbose. Currently the output is limited by the user's terminal settings. I would like to find a way to display the output similar to how the program less does, where the user can scroll/page indefinitely through the output.

Further context: I'm using Thor to make the CLI. Users will run the program in Alpine Linux Docker containers

Comment: Can you not pipe your output through less so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Actually @BenTrewern
That is not an ideal solution for this script for at least two reasons.
1) The script prompts the user for input at various times during execution
2) Less does not play nicely with Thor's coulorized output (For example `say("Some colorized message", :red)`)

Answer (score 0):

Use the highline gem to query the terminal for its size, and then format your output accordingly. Prompt for a key press after you've displayed the number of lines in the second value. Be aware that the size can be changed by resizing the terminal window, so don't store the size and reuse it.

```
require 'highline'
terminal = HighLine::Terminal::IOConsole.new(STDIN,STDOUT)
puts terminal.terminal_size.inspect

=> [80, 24]
```